# Returning and Looping over a List jQuery and Flask

Tags: jquery, python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to be able to loop over the result of a jQuery. I am working from [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/jquery-flask-tutorial/) teaching example:

```
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            $(function() {
              $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
                $.getJSON('/background_process', {
                  proglang: $('input[name="proglang"]').val(),
                }, function(data) {
                  $("#result").text(data.result);
                });
                return false;
              });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='container'>
        <h3>Welcome! Which is the best programming language of them all?</h3>
            <form>
                <input type=text size=5 name=proglang>
                <a href=# id=process_input><button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>
            </form>
        <p id=result></p>
        </div>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

I've tried to modify it to return a list, save it, and loop over it, but this does not seem to work. Here is the relevant portion of what I've tried:

```
, function(data) {
          mylist = $("#result");

          {% for myobj in mylist %}

          <p>{{myobj.textstring}}</p>

          {% endfor %}
                });
                return false;
              });
            });
```

How do I return and loop over the list?

Comment: Does it give an error when it fails?  Can you view the JSON data that you're getting to confirm that you have it formatted correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than loop over the list in JavaScript I set the function in Flask to jsonify and return an html jinja template for an html div that could be inserted into the page. So in the script above:

```
$("#result").text(data.result);
```

became:

```
$("#result").html(data.result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
, function(data) {
          mylist = $("#result");

          {% for myobj in mylist %}

          <p>{{myobj.textstring}}</p>

          {% endfor %}
                });
                return false;
              });
            });
```

This isn't going to work - you're trying to use Jinja template processing `{%` and `%}` on a variable that is not defined in your view, but only defined in Javascript.

You can just use jQuery ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)) to iterate over the result set. The below is untested but should be a good starting point.

```
, function(data) {
          mylist = $("#result");

          $(mylist).each(function () {
              document.write("<p>" + this.textstring + "</p>"); // or similar
          });

          return false;

});
```